# Absolute css paths in Homestead php

Tags: php, css, homestead

I am creating a web app in php and I am using [Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/homestead) to test locally.

I have an MVC structure in my project. Here it is:

[image]

The file in the right side of the picture exists inside the 'Views' folder.

When I link a css with a relative path, it works:
`<link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css"`

But when I try to link it with an absolute path it doesn't:
`<link href="http://fab.app/public/css/bootstrap.min.css"`

Why? And how can I fix it?

Comment: Drop the public. And pick up a tutorial / resource about relative URLs http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005079/absolute-vs-relative-urls/21828923#21828923

Comment: @PeeHa Thank you.
Do you endorse the tactic of defining a constant variable and then change it according to whether you are in production or development environment?
Or just use `href="/css/normalize.css"`?

Comment: I almost always use the latter.